# WPF Button Trigger change child Textblock Foreground XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this button in XAML:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource HeadButton}">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeadButtonText}">Add flavor</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

And I need that when you hover over the button, the `TextBlock` Foreground property should change (I know I can use Content in the button but I'm doing it like this for another reason).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add that textblock in the button style instead and use button triggers...

Comment: I suppose I could (though I don't know how to do it) but I want to know if it's possible to actually target the children of an element in the trigger, or bind a trigger from another control for using it more in the future. Like CSS `.parent:hover .children{...}`

Comment: Nope, that's not how it works... But you can use binding to bind your textbox properties to button properties... and change those from triggers, which should change textbox. But I am not sure if button has a foreground color.

Comment: Yep Button has a Foreground property. So it's not possible for example to Bind the fill from a Button to the Fill property of a Rectangle (since the Button hasn't a Fill property) using XAML?

Comment: You can... let me post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the foreground property of the button, and use triggers to modify it.

```
<Style x:Key="Test" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<Button Style="{StaticResource Test}">
  <TextBlock Text="Click HERe" Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code example of what you're trying to achieve. Although may I note it's not best practice to place a `TextBlock` directly inside the button as the text field is already there, and for the `TextBlock` to use the text field rather than writing between the tags like `HTML`

```
<Button Name="btn">
    <TextBlock Text="Add Flavor">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: Good solution, if the button content consists of more then one element with different foreground colors.